# symfony seperate entities from other code

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a design thinking problem with my symphony application. I have generated entities, which have an firstName and a lastName as properties and the getters and setters are generated. When I now want a function to get the full name, I should write this function in my entity file:

```
public function getName(){
        return $this->getFirstName() . " " . $this->getLastName();
    }
```

I don't like this concept. I want the "clean" generated entity in a file and the additional functions and properties in a different file without getting problems with doctrine or other nice features Have you any nice solution for this?

Comment: Since `getName()` is a method of the entity, where else could it go? It's a simple concatenation of properties and belongs in the entity class.

Comment: You can extended the base class into your own (like FosUser has a complete User model, which is usually extended), and put whatever functions you want there, as long as the relative privacy work, or use a trait to add your new compound-functions.

Comment: Step back a bit and ask yourself why you need a getName method and where will it be used.  I'm guessing it's always for viewing purposes.  And do you always want first then last?  How about last, first? Or maybe adding a title.  If it is mostly for viewing then it might make sense to make a dedicated EntityView class for methods like this.  It's really up to you to understand exactly why you need these sorts of methods.